# How to find p and q in RSA algorithm in python?

Tags: rsa

Suppose we have $N = p*q$ and $C1 = (2*p + 3*q)^{e1} mod N$ and $C2 = (5*p + 7*q)^{e2} mod N$. We know N, e1, e2, C1 and C2, but the problem is that these numbers are really large. We want to find p and q with a python code. In my example N is 600 digits long.

I think that it should be solved as follows:

$N\ =\ p q$

$c1\ ={(\ 2p\ +\ 3q)}^{e_1}mod\ N$

$c2\ ={(\ 5p\ +\ 7q)}^{e_2}mod\ N$

${c_1}^{e_2}\ \ =\ {(2p)}^{e_1e_2}\ +\ {(3q)}^{e_1e_2}\ mod\ N$

${c_2}^{e_1}\ \ =\ {(5p)}^{e_1e_2}\ +\ ({7q)}^{e_1e_2}\ mod\ N$

${{(c}_1}^{e_2})*(5^{e_1e_2})\ -\ {{(c}_2}^{e_1})*(2^{e_1e_2})\ \ \equiv\ {(q}^{e_1e_2})*({15}^{e_1e_2}\ -\ {14}^{e_1e_2})\ mod\ N$

From this we can coclude that:

$gcd({{(c}_1}^{e_2})\ast(5^{e_1e_2})\ -\ {{(c}_2}^{e_1})\ast(2^{e_1e_2}),N)\ =\ q$

I had a python code for that but it takes a long time to run.here is my code:

```
def gcd(a, b):

# Everything divides 0
if (a == 0):
    return b
if (b == 0):
    return a

# base case
if (a == b):
    return a

# a is greater
if (a > b):
    return gcd(a-b, b)
return gcd(a, b-a)
# N = as defined
# e1 = as defined
# e2 = as defined
# c1 = as defined
# c2 = as defined
q = gcd((pow(c1,e2)*pow(5,e1*e2) - pow(c2,e1)*pow(2,e1*e2)),N)
print(q)
```

I also tried some other codes, but none of them worked

Comment: We won't just give you a Python program to solve this.  If you need a hint, I would mention that $(2p+3q)^{e_1} = 2^{e_1}p^{e_1} + 3^{e_1}q^{e_1} \pmod N$

Comment: I edited my question and mentioned my attempts. please open my question

Comment: use the third argument of the pow, too. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_pow.asp

Comment: They haven't reopened the question, so I'll give my response as a comment: you have a 95% answer, so I'll point out what your missing: the only issues are two things in your Python code: firstly, $c_1^{e_2}$ is a huge integer (and `pow(c1,e2)` will ask Python to compute it); your computer doesn't have that much memory.  Instead, what you want is `pow(c1,e2,N)`, which has python compute that modulo N (which is what you need); same for your other `pow` calls; secondly, the result of the subtraction may be negative; your gcd code will infinite loop if that happens.  Easy to fix...